# Product Scheduling on existing opportunities

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product

Is there any way to mass establish scheduling for existing opportunities? Product scheduler works, and when a new opportunity is created and that specific product is added, everything works perfectly.

However, I would like to be able to set it for previous opportunities which contain that product as well.

Currently the only way I've found is to go into each opportunity line item and clicking 'Establish', but that would be too much work for all our opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data loader and do the mass update on the product scheduler.